# how to get data from listview by clicking item on listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, onclick

I have a listview in my application and its populated with all the currently installed applications on my device, also i have it getting the list of permissions from all the installed applications.

My question is how do i get the listview clickable so that i can get the list of permissions for the application you click on in the listview?

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              

            }
        });
```

In a few days we will be uploading an elaborate tutorial on http://p-xr.com. Be sure to check it out :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set itemclicklistener to listen all item click events.
Add this code to the above code

```
lv.setClickable(true);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
Object o = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
String str=(String)o;//As you are using Default String Adapter
/* write you handling code like...
// do whatever u want to do with 'f' File object
*/ 
}
});
```

Comment: just wonder, why so you have the "File f = new File..." there. Is that getting the position of the click is it?

Answer (score 1):

We can directly use the View parameter inside the onItemClick() to get the value from that item in list. 
Try this....

```
mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position,long id)
    {
    TextView textview =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvInVisitorName)).getText().toString();
    }
    });
```

I am taking the value form the item of list in the textview